# GeoServer 2.23.2 Which versions of the WCS service are supported?

Tags: geoserver, wcs

I have installed GeoServer 2.23.2 and publish a Raster as WCS. I notice that GeoServer supported 1.0.0 and 1.1.1，but I can use "http://192.168.40.161:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&coverageId=Raster__C1000002008091120000816_NDVI&format=tiff"gain Data. I don't know why?

[image]

Comment: It supports all the versions listed on the home page

Answer (score 2):

The message you see under the "Web Coverage Service" can be edited in the WCS admin panel, you can modify it to say 2.0 too, it won't change what GeoServer can do.

The actual supported versions are the ones in the boxes below.

Comment: I understand. Thank you